# iOS Core data update to data not getting saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using core data entity named `CrumbPoint` which stores latitude and longitude and it points to (has relation to) another entity named `HRRecord`. CrumbPoint is created this way:

```
CrumbPoint *crumbPoint = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CrumbPoint"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
crumbPoint.lat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lat];
crumbPoint.lon = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lon];
crumbPoint.velocity = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:velocity];
crumbPoint.date = [NSDate date];

// Since this use search query, always refresh from DB
// The following fetch using NSFetchRequest when the record is available.
HrRecord * hr = [HRRecord hrRecordWithTitle:title inManagedObjectContext:context];
crumbPoint.inRecord = hr;
```

HrRecord has a field named `distance` which is what I need to update whenever the device has a location update. (I am keeping track of user jogging). For every location update, a new `CrumbPoint` is created, and it points to the same `HrRecord` for the same jogging session. The new distance between previous location and the new location needs to be calculated and the distance for the `HrRecord` needs to be updated.

However my problem is that every time I'm getting the HrRecord (Maybe this is a bad design, but I'm using `NSFetchRequest` to query for the `HrRecord` each time for a new location update.)

Now when I try to update:

```
HrRecord * hr = crumbPoint.inRecord;
float oldDistance = [hr.distance doubleValue];
// code to calculate distance here, then, update
hr.distance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: newDistanceUpdate];
```

`hr.distance` would always be 0 before update, even though every time after the update I can print out new value. I tried sending `save` to managed object context but it doesn't seem to work either. Why is that?

EDIT:
Here is the code to inserting. Maybe the bug is not about saving, after the context is saved I tried pulling out the record with `[HrRecord HrRecordWithTitle:title inManagedObjectContext:context]` and distance IS updated for that round. But next time the location update comes in it's 0 again for some reason. I gotta check for more code. :/

```
+(HrRecord *)HrRecordWithTitle: (NSString *)title
                      inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    HrRecord * record = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"HrRecord"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", title];
    NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * records = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!records || records.count > 1) {
        // Nil, or more than one is an error
    } else if (records.count == 0) {
        // Create a new record with starting duration of 0
        record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HrRecord" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        record.title = title;
        record.duration = @0.0;
        record.distance = @0.0;
        record.date = [NSDate date];
    } else { // Recrod exists, exactly one
        record = [records lastObject];
        // update duration
        record.duration = @([record.duration intValue] + 1);
    }

    return record;
}
```

Comment: could you post some code on how do you actually insert that inRecord in proper `NSManagedObjectContext`? I assume your data model is properly set and `HrRecord` class is also generated right away from that model, is that correct? I've noticed a typo: 'HRRecord' instead of 'HrRecord' in class method invocation.

Comment: I'm don't know your implementation but try to perform a `save` on the context that is fetching the data just before fetch, this will `refresh` the context.

Comment: Silly enough, I'm resetting the record distance whenever I'm creating a new CrumbPoint. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

What Managed Object Context do you use? You should use context which created in your current thread.